# typedef for template inside template

Tags: c++, class, templates, typedef, smart-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

I have a class that creates a smart pointer when creating a object and passing the desired class as template parameter. And I have another class that needs to use that smart pointer in another class.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

//smart pointer class

```
template<typename T>
class IntrusivePtr
{
public:
    IntrusivePtr()
    {
        cout << "IntrusivePtr()";
    }
};
```

//class for which I need a smart pointer which is also template

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        cout << "A()";
    }
    typedef IntrusivePtr< A<T> > my_ptr;
};
```

//class that uses the smart pointer.

```
template<typename T>
class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        cout << "B()";
    }

    typedef A<T>::my_ptr x;
};



int main()
{
    B<int> ob;

    return 0;
}
```

Can this be achieved in c++?
I know the new C++11 supports `typedef`s for things like this but I'm using the old standard :(
Compiling this I'm getting some bad ass errors:

> C:\Users\jacob\typedef_template_class-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MSVC2008__Qt_SDK__Debug..\typedef_template_class\main.cpp:41:
> error: C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'x'
>
> C:\Users\jacob\typedef_template_class-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MSVC2008__Qt_SDK__Debug..\typedef_template_class\main.cpp:41:
> error: C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'x'
>
> C:\Users\jacob\typedef_template_class-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MSVC2008__Qt_SDK__Debug..\typedef_template_class\main.cpp:41:
> error: C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int

EDIT:
Sorry, I changed some things and the error code. This is how I want it to be. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        cout << "B()";
    }

    typedef typename A< B >::my_ptr x;
};
```

You should use `typename`, since `my_prt` is `dependent name`.

Comment: To know more about the dependent names, check out this [excelent SO answer!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/499359) :) for me it was quite useful.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Thank you. It's worth reading

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `A<B>::my_ptr` is a dependend name (it depends on `B<T>` and therefore on the template parameter `T`). For this reason the compiler doesn't know if it is supposed to be a type or a variable when parsing the template. In that situation it assumes that `my_ptr` is not a type, unless you explecitely tell it so. Therefore you need to add `typename`, just like the compiler told you to do:

```
typedef typename A< B >::my_ptr x;
```

For a more complete explanation [look at this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/201270).

Comment: thank you for the response and link. I'm starting to read right now!